# Public IP address does not work in internal network

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, nat

I have configured port forwarding to my system from the router configuration menu, when I try to access the public IP address in the internal network it does not respond but it is accessible outside of the router network such as mobile data.

Refer to the configurations of my router as below;

[image: router configurations]

Comment: Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: if you have an on-demand VPN available, you can proxy through it to test the ports. Note that if that's targeting a synology NAS, I do not recommend you expose 5001. I believe they have a reverse tunneling mechanism that would be preferable to forwarding a port to the public.